# How do I resize a cell in a tableview with grouped cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a grouped tableview and need to resize 1 cell where the enclosed cell.detailTextLabel has exceeded the size of the cell (i.e. about 3 lines worth).

Is there any easy way for the cell to auto-size itself to it's contents or otherwise, how do I change the size of that particular cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UITableViewDelegate` has a method called `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. Just have it return the desired height for each row.

Comment: How can you work out the height based on the text in the label?

Comment: Check out the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method of NSString. Once you know how much space your text label needs, you can determine the height of the cell.